# Android MediaController Next Previous Buttons

Tags: android, button, mediacontroller

So, For Android's MediaController I found this "The "previous" and "next" buttons are hidden until setPrevNextListeners() has been called."  I'd like to show the next and previous.  Can someone help me understand how to set this up?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a VideoView control withing an activity, (let's call it videoView), you will want to attach a MediaController to it. Try the following:

```
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    //Handle next click here
  }
}, new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    //Handle previous click here
  }
});
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This is audio only using mediaplayer and mediacontroller. Can that type of setup work this way?

Comment: It appears to work without this line `videoView.setMediaController(mc);` at the end for mediaplayer.  I guess it's ok.  Thanks.